GitHub Actions Runner Controller on Azure AKS and VM serving as a proxy for the AKS cluster not able to push using docker/build-push-action@v6 action
I'm using a self-hosted GitHub Actions runner setup with Actions Runner Controller (ARC) on Azure AKS, along with a small VM serving as a proxy for the AKS. My self-hosted Docker registry is set up with a  Nginx reverse proxy and is configured to only accept requests from the VM proxy server from azure. I'm experiencing issues when trying to push Docker images to the registry using docker/build-push-action@v6 in GitHub Actions. The push works flawlessly when I build and push the Docker images using regular Docker commands in the pipeline script, but it fails with a 403 Forbidden error response when using the GitHub Action. I suspect this is because the docker/build-push-action@v6 GitHub Action is not utilizing the proxy VM configured for the AKS cluster.
I also tried to include the proxy's on builds-args but its still not working.
What could be causing this discrepancy, and how can I resolve it?
name: poc
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: selfhosted-ubuntu-runners

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Login to selfhosted-registry.com
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: selfhosted-registry.com
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASS }}  

      - name: Build and Push Docker Image
        id: push-tag
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          context: .  
          push: true
          tags: "selfhosted-registry.com/testrepo:01"
          build-args: |
            http_proxy=${{ secrets.http_proxy }}
            https_proxy=${{ secrets.https_proxy }}


You have to configure your repository - Settings -> Action -> General -> Workflow permissions and choose read and write permissions.If you add a permission to write to contents, you will be able to push to your repository using GitHub

In above question you  said pipeline script are you using Azure DevOps with git or only git

Do you have docker file in your repo of git ?

The 403 Forbidden error response when using the GitHub Action  is  due to Workflow permissions.requires the contents permission to be write.
You have to configure your repository - Settings -> Action -> General -> Workflow permissions and choose read and write permissions.

To  add write permission  to contents of  GITHUB_TOKEN with   GitHub refer to this SO.

The below sample GitHub Actions workflow  How to use  proxy settings for your jobs :

name: poc

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: selfhosted-ubuntu-runners

    env:
      LOG_FILE: devproxy.log
      DEVPROXY_VERSION: v0.18.0
      # Proxy server configuration
      http_proxy: ${{ secrets.http_proxy }}
      https_proxy: ${{ secrets.https_proxy }}

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

      - name: Login to selfhosted-registry.com
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: selfhosted-registry.com
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASS }}

      # Cache Dev Proxy
      - name: Cache Dev Proxy
        id: cache-devproxy
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ./devproxy
          key: devproxy-ubuntu-${{ env.DEVPROXY_VERSION }}

      - name: Install Dev Proxy
        if: steps.cache-devproxy.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: bash -c "$(curl -sL https://aka.ms/devproxy/setup.sh)" -- ${{ env.DEVPROXY_VERSION }}

      - name: Run Dev Proxy
        run: /bin/bash run-dev-proxy.sh

      - name: Build and Push Docker Image
        id: push-tag
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: "selfhosted-registry.com/testrepo:01"
          build-args: |
            http_proxy=${{ secrets.http_proxy }}
            https_proxy=${{ secrets.https_proxy }}

      - name: Upload Dev Proxy logs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: ${{ env.LOG_FILE }}
          path: ${{ env.LOG_FILE }}

      - name: Upload Dev Proxy reports
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: Reports
          path: ./*Reporter*

      - name: Write summary
        run: |
          cat SomePlugin_MarkdownReporter.md >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY


Refer this MSDOC to Use Dev Proxy with GitHub Actions 
I Refer this MSDOC to to deploy self-hosted GitHub Actions Runners on AKS .

